# OpenCV Stitching RGB and Depth (Intel RealSense)

Tags: opencv, opencv-stitching

I have a C++ application utilizing both realsense2 and opencv2 libraries. I'm pulling depth and RGB frames from two D415 camera. I'm able to stitch the RGB frames without issue; however, after much research I'm unable to find any example of how to duplicate steps from the RGB frame stitch to the depth frames. Does anyone know how to replicate stitching steps from one stitching job (RGB in my case) to another stitching job (depth in my case)?

I've looked at the Stitcher class reference documentation here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html

If anyone has done this before and could provide some guidance that would be great.

Here is the working code I'm using to stitch (shortened):

```
// Start a streaming pipeline for each connected camera

for (auto && device : context.query_devices())

{

    string serial = device.get_info(RS2_CAMERA_INFO_SERIAL_NUMBER);

    pipeline pipeline(context);

    config config;

    config.enable_device(serial);

    config.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_COLOR, 1280, 720, RS2_FORMAT_BGR8, 15);

    config.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH, 1280, 720);

    config.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_INFRARED, 1);

    pipeline.start(config);

    pipelines.emplace_back(pipeline);

    colorizers[serial] = colorizer();

}



map<int, frame> render_frames;



while(true)

{

    vector<Mat> mats;

    vector<frame> new_frames;

    for (auto && pipeline : pipelines)

    {

        frameset frameset = pipeline.wait_for_frames();

        if (frameset)

        {

            mats.push_back(frame_to_mat(frameset.get_color_frame()));

        }

    }

    Mat stitchedImage;

    Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(Stitcher::PANORAMA);

    Stitcher::Status stitcherStatus = stitcher->stitch(mats, stitchedImage);

    if (stitcherStatus == Stitcher::OK)

    {

        imshow("Stitched Image", stitchedImage);
        auto k = waitKey(200);

    } else {

        cout << "Error stitching image.\n";

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to achieve? I dont think stitching depth images makes a lot of sense, since depth values are relative to the camera position. E.g. if you move the canera forward, the same object's point will get two very different depth values. Maybe instead you want something like SLAM? Have a look at "kinect fusion" method.

Comment: @Micka - Thanks for the quick response! The goal here is I have two Intel RealSense cameras (D415) the viewing angle is pretty poor on these ~70 degrees. If I combine two of them I can achieve ~110 degrees (any more and OpenCV doesn't like to stitch the images). I'm trying to stitch RGB images take simultaneously from the cameras, detect the faces using a haar cascade, then check if the detected faces have depth using the depth frame/image. The end goal will be a face detection that doesn't identify 2d pictures of faces (think photos on a living room wall, or displayed on a screen, etc.)

Comment: ah ok, this makes more sense. Unfortunately I dont know whether you can extract the matched keypoints from opencv's stitcher class directly. In wost case you could change opencv's code (it is open source).

Comment: Are the 2 depth cameras statically mounted so the position from the first to the second camera stays the same?

Comment: @TeddybearCrisis - Yes they are statically mounted; however, the environment will change. I.E. statically mounted in a box with a raspberry pi; however, the box will move from place to place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore distortion then stitching is just computing a transform from one image origin to another. And technically you have everything you need already. Here's a **VERY NAIVE** approach.

Within each single camera (provided in the hardware specification) there is:

```
depth_origin -> rgb_origin
("->" represents a transform)
```

The OpenCV stitcher can [estimate a transform](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#a4c25557af4d40a79a4d1f23d9548131d) between the two rgb images so you have

```
cam1_rgb_origin -> cam2_rgb_origin
```

So you can compute:

```
cam1_depth -> cam1_rgb -> cam2_rgb -> cam2_depth
```

Your approach is a bit unusual but it might work sufficiently since the camera specs are provided in the realsense docs and I think each sensor is well aligned.

**A bit of a warning though:**

In general two cameras are never perfectly aligned. Hence for a more elaborate solution I'd avoid using the transform computed via image stitching. I'd rather calibrate the cameras on the static mount to obtain the extrinsic camera parameters. That is just the 3D transform from camera coordinate origin 1 to camera coordinate origin 2. Using this transform you'd create a 3D point cloud of the sensor data in a unified coordinate system containting both camera's points. Finally you can render this point cloud to a depth image from ANY perspective you choose and project the rgb images onto it to make it viable for the face detection you want to use. Camera calibration can be a royal pain especially when the camera's perspectives don't intersect a lot. So only follow this elaborate approach if your results don't suffice.

Sorry but for time sake I can't go into more detail. But I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: This is exactly what I figured you were alluding to when you asked your question. I had given it some thought after you asked if they were statically mounted and figured this might be the right approach. I didn't think about the point cloud, that is a good suggestion. I would update the thread with code; however, this is a private project so I'll just say that this suggestion has worked for me and I have a working prototype using the method you outlined. Thanks again! Cheers!

Comment: Goog thing is, that the realsense cams already provide rectified/undistorted images. This makes the "naive" approach pretty straight forward IMHO. Unless the cam's perspectives divert too much I'd give it a try. It's related to what I usually do (https://www.icy3d.com/demo). Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Intel SDK provides rotation and translation matrix between depth and RGB of the individual camera.  With that matrix you align the depth and rgb data.

For multi-camera, calibrating multiple cameras is not as easy we think.  Intel suggest "vicalib" software, you can try once.